# I have 2 VStacks that needs to have the same edge spacing

Tags: swiftui

I have 3 Vstacks But the issue is with the bottom 2. I want the last VStack edge ( where the rounded edge square meet the leading and trailing edge to be the same as the 2nd VStack's. The issue is with dynamic screen sizes.

```
Vstack
{
  stuff
}
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .shadow(radius: 1))
.padding()
Vstack
{
  stuff
}
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .shadow(radius: 1))
//.padding(.horizontal, geometry.size.width * 0.15) // close but not right, still slightly off when switching screens sizes(iphones)
//.padding([.leading, .trailing], 58) // Needs to be fixed. works on only 1 screen
```

How it looks now

[image: Sample Image]

How it Should look like

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your 3 VStack views are nested inside a VStack. The 2nd view is greedy since it takes up the entire width of the parent view with the `Toggle` component, while the VStack parent view still has `.center` alignment. And the 3rd view, by default, just has enough space to fit its contents at the center horizontally. To fix this, simply add:

```swift
//3rd view
VStack {
  ...
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

By doing this, you're saying that the 3rd view should have a frame's width as large as possible with its parent. And in this scenario, it's 2nd view width.

Following the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/frame(minwidth:idealwidth:maxwidth:minheight:idealheight:maxheight:alignment:)):

> If no minimum or maximum constraint is specified in a given dimension, the frame adopts the sizing behavior of its child in that dimension

**Updated:** Let's say your View is `GroupVStack`.

```swift
struct GroupVStack: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      //1st: simple, traffic...
      VStack { }

      //2nd: monthly...
      VStack { }

      //3rd
      VStack { }
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    } 
  }
}
```

Then you can reuse the View from outside with or without padding. The purpose is to make it more reusable.

```swift
struct GroupVStackContainer: View {
  var body: some View {
    GroupVStack().padding()
  }
}
```

Comment: This extends the screen going from edge to edge. perhaps we have to add some padding?

Comment: Exactly, in my opinion, adding some padding from the outside is better from the inside in this case.